# Multiplication of floating point numbers in MIPS

Tags: floating-point, mips, multiplication

How can I multiply two floating point numbers in mips? I have written the following code:

```
mul.s $f0,$f1,$f0

mflo $f0
```

But it gives an error in the second statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$f0` already contains the result; the second statement is not needed.